# Unable to Deploy Primefaces 12 Application on Payara 6 using Netbeans 17

Tags: jsf, primefaces, payara, jakarta-migration

I am currently using NetBeans 17 IDE for developing a Maven-based JSF/JSP application using Primefaces version 12. I've been deploying my application on Payara 5 without any issues, but recently, due to support discontinuation for Payara 5 and associated errors, I've decided to switch to Payara 6.

Unfortunately, I've run into a problem where the application fails to deploy on Payara 6 and throws the following error:

```
SEVERE:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to add listener of type: org.primefaces.webapp.UploadedFileCleanerListener, because it does not implement any of the required ServletContextListener, ServletContextAttributeListener, ServletRequestListener, ServletRequestAttributeListener, HttpSessionListener, or HttpSessionAttributeListener interfaces
```

To resolve this, I tried using both JDK 11 and JDK 17 for Payara, but the issue persists. Additionally, I attempted to install Jakarta 10, but NetBeans 17 doesn't recognize it as a Java Platform, forcing me to abandon this approach.

Given this scenario, could anyone suggest a compatible combination of Primefaces, Java, and JDK that I could use in a NetBeans development environment for later deployment on a virtual machine? I'm open to considering alternatives to Payara, given the circumstance.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you asked the Payara? As you're switching to 6 because it has support.

Comment: I can't afford for commercial support.

Comment: Check out WEB-INF/lib of your WAR. You probably have some Servlet API JAR in there causing a funny class loading issue.

Comment: I am so sad this has been labelled as a duplicate. The issue is not the same. This is a very bad system that allows someone else, who has no idea of what I am facing, to decide another one has the same issue. If this had not been labelled as a duplicate, someone else would have helped me.